# Issue with contact deployment on etherscan

Tags: contract-deployment, tokens, etherscan

I have created a new token and deployed it on Ropsten Network using Metamask. I have also followed the norms of ERC20 Token Standard.

Now, when I am trying to find my token using Contract address on EtherScan (Ropsten) ERC20 Token Search box, I get the following message:

[image: CWF Currency]

I ensure you that i have already verified the decimal attribute which is set to 8 in my code.

What can be the possible reason for not able to display decimal units in my contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your [contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0890fe640f27a74665e1fdb5a0c532e154b7020e#code) (it would have been easier if you'd posted a link to it rather than just the image, but nevermind).

You need to create the function `decimals()`, not `decimal()` (note the "s").

Specifically, your contract contains a function signature for `decimal()`, namely `0x76809ce3`, but not for `decimals()`, which is `0x313ce567`. For ERC20, you need the latter.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. That make sense! And thanks, i'll keep in mind to put the link next time for sure.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" - that's how things work around here :-)